# what does compass:server mean in grunt?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, compass-sass

I encountered this snippet of code, can someone explain what does `compass:server` mean?

```
compass: {
  files: ['<%= config.src %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
  tasks: ['compass:server', 'autoprefixer']
},
```

Answer (score 0):

`compass` is the name of a Grunt task (compiling Sass to CSS using Compass), and `server` is the name of a subtask. So, an example from [the documentation](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass):

```
compass: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      sassDir: 'sass',
      cssDir: 'css',
      environment: 'production'
    }
  },
  dev: {
    options: {
      sassDir: 'sass',
      cssDir: 'css'
    }
  }
  server: {
    options: {
      sassDir: 'sass',
      cssDir: 'css'
    }
  }
}
```

Using this configuration you could choose to run the `dist`, `dev` or `server` subtasks (with associated options) with `compass:dist`, `compass:dev` or `compass:server` commands.

I use [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) all the time in my development. It's worth checking out if you want to take some of the complexity out of a development workflow. The alternative is new kid on the block, [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/).